# Jquery UI Accordion and JQuery Grid plugin not going well together

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have used Jquery -UI accordion plugin for menu (since it looks neat) and Jquery -grid rails plugin for my data. I have a vertical menu and data on the right side, however the style of the menu disappears and only grid is showing up properly. Anyone faced this issue before ?

Comment: some code would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you aren't having CSS issues.  My guess would be that the CSS directives are stepping on each other.  Use Firebug in Firefox to verify what CSS files are doing what.